# VPAID jwplayer 7.12.8 setAdVolume bug

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

Found this bug in JWPlayer **7.12.8**.

When VPAID validators (see the links below) try to set volume => 0.9 jwplayer send a method setAdVolume with value in percents, e.g. 0.009000000000000001.

- Volume = 0 => setAdVolume(0);
- Volume = 0.5 => setAdVolume(0.005);
- Volume = 0.9 => setAdVolume(0.009000000000000001);
- Volume = 1 => setAdVolume(0.01);

As you can see, the volume is divided by 100. Previous JWPlayer version **7.10.7** works good and has no this bug. Other validators which don't use JWPlayer also works good.

Validators with bug (7.12.8):

- developer.jwplayer.com/tools/ad-tester/
- demo.jwplayer.com/ad-tester/
- demo.jwplayer.com/vpaid2/

Validator without bug (7.10.7):

- http://vastcreator.weborama.nl/index/preview/

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: The question is "How to awoid this?" Is it a JWPlayer 7.12.8 bug?

Comment: Can you not just upgrade to a later version?

Comment: Those validators are owned by developer.jwplayer.com, so their developers update players, not me.